# Merging multiple dictionaries that have dictionaries in list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have several dictionaries (perhaps 10s of them) that formed like below:

```
{'stdout': [{'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'B', 'host': None, 'count': 135},
            {'foo': 'C', 'bar': 'B', 'host': 'egg', 'count': 28},
            {'foo': 'D', 'bar': 'E', 'host': 'apple', 'count': 1},
            {'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'E', 'host': 'chicken breast', 'count': 1},
            {'foo': 'C', 'bar': 'F', 'host': 'carrot', 'count': 1}],
 'stderr': ''}
```

I want to **combine all those dictionaries with adding 'count' key's integer with same 'foo','bar' and 'host' keys** (None is NoneType)

For example, for 2 dictionaries

```
dictA = {'stdout': [{'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'B', 'host': None, 'count': 135},
            {'foo': 'C', 'bar': 'B', 'host': 'egg', 'count': 28},
            {'foo': 'D', 'bar': 'E', 'host': 'apple', 'count': 2},
            {'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'E', 'host': 'chicken breast', 'count': 1},
            {'foo': 'C', 'bar': 'F', 'host': 'carrot', 'count': 1}],
 'stderr': ''}

dictB = {'stdout': [{'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'B', 'host': None, 'count': 280},
            {'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'B', 'host': 'orange', 'count': 46},
            {'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'E', 'host': 'pineapple', 'count': 3},
            {'foo': 'D', 'bar': 'E', 'host': 'apple', 'count': 2},
            {'foo': 'C', 'bar': 'F', 'host': 'carrot', 'count': 1}],
 'stderr': ''}
```

Then the merged version should be

```
dictMerged = {'stdout': [{'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'B', 'host': None, 'count': 415},
            {'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'B', 'host': 'orange', 'count': 46},
            {'foo': 'C', 'bar': 'B', 'host': 'egg', 'count': 28},
            {'foo': 'D', 'bar': 'E', 'host': 'apple', 'count': 4},
            {'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'E', 'host': 'pineapple', 'count': 3},
            {'foo': 'C', 'bar': 'F', 'host': 'carrot', 'count': 2},
            {'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'E', 'host': 'chicken breast', 'count': 1}],
 'stderr': ''}
```

Note that the dictionary elements in list's order changed after 'count' summed.

I have tried to combine them for same 'host' as a first step like below but it was not same as what I wanted:

```
hostname1 = {i["host"]: i for i in dictA['stdout']}
hostname2 = {i["host"]: i for i in dictB['stdout']}
all_host = hostname1|hostname2
{key: value + b[key] for key, value in a.items()}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### One approach

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

# creat a dictionary (defaultdict) to put the dictionaries with matching foo, bar, host in the same list
groups = defaultdict(list, {(d['foo'], d['bar'], d['host']): [d] for d in dictB['stdout']})
for d in dictA["stdout"]:
    key = (d['foo'], d['bar'], d['host'])
    groups[key].append(d)

# use item getter for better readability
count = itemgetter("count")

# create new list of dictionaries, sum the count values
ds = [{'foo': f, 'bar': b, 'host': h, 'count': sum(count(d) for d in v)} for (f, b, h), v in groups.items()]

# sort the list of dictionaries in decreasing order 
res = {"stdout": sorted(ds, key=count, reverse=True), "stderr": ""}
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'stderr': '',
 'stdout': [{'bar': 'B', 'count': 415, 'foo': 'A', 'host': None},
            {'bar': 'B', 'count': 46, 'foo': 'A', 'host': 'orange'},
            {'bar': 'B', 'count': 28, 'foo': 'C', 'host': 'egg'},
            {'bar': 'E', 'count': 4, 'foo': 'D', 'host': 'apple'},
            {'bar': 'E', 'count': 3, 'foo': 'A', 'host': 'pineapple'},
            {'bar': 'F', 'count': 2, 'foo': 'C', 'host': 'carrot'},
            {'bar': 'E', 'count': 1, 'foo': 'A', 'host': 'chicken breast'}]}
```

For more on each of the functions and data structures used in the code above see: [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

#### One alternative

Use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import pprint
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby


def key(d):
    return d["foo"], d["bar"], d["host"] or ""


count = itemgetter("count")
lst = sorted(dictA["stdout"] + dictB["stdout"], key=key)
groups = groupby(lst, key=key)
ds = [{'foo': f, 'bar': b, 'host': h or None, 'count': sum(count(d) for d in vs)} for (f, b, h), vs in groups]
res = {"stdout": sorted(ds, key=count, reverse=True), "stderr": ""}
print(res)
```

This second approach has two caveats:

1. The time complexity is `O(nlogn)` the first one was `O(n)`
2. In order to sort the list of dictionaries it needs to replace `None` by the empty string `""`.

#### Multiple dictionaries

If you have multiple dictionaries you can change the first approach to:

```
# create a dictionary (defaultdict) to put the dictionaries with matching foo, bar, host in the same list
groups = defaultdict(list, {(d['foo'], d['bar'], d['host']): [d] for d in dictB['stdout']})

# create a list with all the dictionaries from multiple dict
data = []
lst = [dictA]  # change this line to contain all the dictionaries except B
for d in lst:
    data.extend(d["stdout"])

for d in data:
    key = (d['foo'], d['bar'], d['host'])
    groups[key].append(d)

# use item getter for better readability
count = itemgetter("count")

# create new list of dictionaries, sum the count values
ds = [{'foo': f, 'bar': b, 'host': h, 'count': sum(count(d) for d in v)} for (f, b, h), v in groups.items()]

# sort the list of dictionaries in decreasing order
res = {"stdout": sorted(ds, key=count, reverse=True), "stderr": ""}
```

#### What is `itemgetter`?

From the documentation:

> Return a callable object that fetches item from its operand using the
> operand’s **getitem**() method. If multiple items are specified,
> returns a tuple of lookup values.

Is equivalent to:

```
def itemgetter(*items):
    if len(items) == 1:
        item = items[0]
        def g(obj):
            return obj[item]
    else:
        def g(obj):
            return tuple(obj[item] for item in items)
    return g
```

Comment: `d` is a dictionary and `count` is a function

Comment: accidentally deleted my first comment :( but yes, thank you

Comment: @Ludacia Included a version for multiple dictionaries